# how to return observable from function that has a promise

Tags: angular, promise, rxjs, observable

I have a function with a promise in it.
I would like the function to return observable when the promise occur.
See my code:

```
  public exportAsExcel() : Observable<void>
  {
    let workbook = new Workbook();
    .....
    ......
    workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => 
    {
        this.doSomething(data);
        return of();
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html), which turns your promise to an observable:

```ts
import { from } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

// ...

return from(workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()).pipe(
 map(...)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
return new Observable(obs=>{

       let workbook = new Workbook();
        .....
       ......
       workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer().then((data) => 
       {
          this.doSomething(data);
          return obs.next(data);
        });
    })
```

Or using rxjs `from` and `map`

```js
return from(workbook.xlsx.writeBuffer()).pipe(map(data => {
   // process something
   return dataTransformed
}))
```